# React blocky error `Uncaught TypeError: Invalid block definition for type: buy_qty_block`

Tags: reactjs

Here is my blocky-config file

```
    {
        kind: "category",
        name: "Buy or Sell",
        colour: 260,
        contents: [
        {
            kind: "block",
            type: "buy_qty_block",
        },
        {
            kind: "block",
            type: "sell_qty_block",
        }
        ],
    },
```

For `buy_qty_block` type it is calling below function

```
    Blockly.Blocks["buy_qty_block"] = {
        init: function () {
          this.jsonInit({
            type: "buy_qty_block",
            message0: "Buy %1 ",
            args0: [
              {
                type: "field_number",
                name: "BUY_AMOUNT",
              },
              // , {
              //   "type": "input_dummy",
              //   "name": "ASSETSLIST",
              // }
            ],
            message1: "%1 ",
            args1: [
              {
                type: "input_dummy",
                name: "ASSETSLIST",
              },
            ],
            previousStatement: true,
            nextStatement: "Action",
            extensions: ["assets_list_extension"],
          });
        },
      };
```

It is giving below error when this type calls
Any idea how to solve this error ?

```
      block.ts:264 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid block definition for type: buy_qty_block
            at new n (block.ts:264:15)
            at a.<anonymous> (createSuper.js:11:24)
            at new a (block_svg.ts:155:5)
            at ah.newBlock (blockly.ts:564:14)
            at Ya (blocks.ts:404:27)
            at Oa (blocks.ts:361:17)
            at wa (blocks.ts:325:10)
            at t.value (flyout_base.ts:761:24)
            at t.value (flyout_base.ts:669:30)
            at t.value (flyout_base.ts:604:29)
```

Please take a look how can i solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and I think it may be the same.

In my case, it was that when loading the saved project, the block was not yet defined. Try adding a

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  // Here the logic to load the project
}, 1000)
```

If this doesn't fix it, try setting the toolbox (in your case, blockly-config after defining the block.